# Travis CI : unable to upgrade npm version

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci, npm-install

I try to upgrade the npm version used by Travis CI in the `.travis.yml` config file :

`language: node_js
node_js: 0.12
before_install: npm install -g npm@latest`

But it change nothing when I look to the Travis job's logs :

`node --version
v0.6.21-pre
npm --version
1.1.37`

I also don't understand why the node version is 0.6 because I explicitly tell Travis to use the 0.12 version...

But my main problem is why the npm version is not updated. I have many `No compatible version found` errors when installing the npm dependencies. (I have this exact same issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7219).

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't the version be quoted, so that it's a string and not a number?

Comment: I also tried this, same result

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use lists for `node_js` and `before_install`. For example:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.12
before_install:
  - npm install -g npm@latest
```

On an unrelated note though, v0.12 will no longer be supported after the end of this year, so unless you really need to use that version, you should consider upgrading to something like v6.x which is the current LTS release branch as of this writing.